# The getter 'value' was called on null from FutureBuilder<DataSnapshot>

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I can get this result from these two things(data structure from `Firebase Realtime Database` and code below).

[image]

```dart
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_swiper/flutter_swiper.dart';

class GetMealScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GetMealScreenState createState() => _GetMealScreenState();
}

class _GetMealScreenState extends State<GetMealScreen> {

  DatabaseReference itemRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("testtest").child("test");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body:
        Container(
          child:
          FutureBuilder<DataSnapshot>(
            future: itemRef.once(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {

              List<String> menuList = [
                snapshot.data.value["tt"].toString(),
              ];

              final double card_width = 370;
              final double card_upper_height = 210;

              return
                Container(
                  height: card_upper_height,
                  width: card_width,
                  child:
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 0),
                    child: Swiper(//
                      control: SwiperControl(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      pagination: SwiperPagination(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight
                      ),
                      itemCount: menuList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                        return
                          Text(
                            menuList[index],
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 40,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                );
            },
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

but the problem is whenever I try to access this screen I get the following error.

```dart
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device AOSP on IA Emulator...
Reloaded 5 of 685 libraries in 702ms.
I/flutter (15990): hi

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<DataSnapshot>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<DataSnapshot>#84ed7):
The getter 'value' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: value

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  FutureBuilder<DataSnapshot> file:///Users/mingukkim/tubuc1.1.3/lib/GetMealMenu.dart:21:11
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      _GetMealScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:Tubuc/GetMealMenu.dart:26:31)
#2      _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:751:55)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4683:28)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4566:15)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I thought it has appeared because `snapshot.data.value["tt"].toString()` returns null value but it isn't so I can't get a sense of what's wrong.. Also, I found a similar problem on Google, but I couldn't find a problem with FutureBuilder like mine. Can you tell me what's wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are trying to access `snapshot.data.value` before the Future has completed. You need to wrap it in a `if (snapshot.hasData)` so your code is executed once the Future has returned. Take a look at the class on flutter.dev for a good example: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if(snapshot.hasData){
  List<String> menuList = [
                snapshot.data.value["tt"].toString(),
              ];

              final double card_width = 370;
              final double card_upper_height = 210;

              return
                Container(
                  height: card_upper_height,
                  width: card_width,
                  child:
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 0),
                    child: Swiper(//
                      control: SwiperControl(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      pagination: SwiperPagination(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight
                      ),
                      itemCount: menuList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                        return
                          Text(
                            menuList[index],
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 40,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                );
            },
       // By default, show a loading spinner.
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
         },
          }
```

Since the `FutureBuilder` is used for asynchronous operation, then use `hasData` to make that it enters  `snapshot.data.value["tt"].toString(),` after obtaining the value from the database.